# Is there a simple way to restore widget sizes in Qt?

Tags: qt, qtgui

I'm looking for a way to preserve the size of windows in a Qt app.

I've seen that there is the possibility of using the following method for every widget:

```
saveGeometry()
```

But really, I don't find this a satisfactioning method. Is there something like `setAutosaveGeometry(True)`?

I'm especially looking for a way to store the widths of table columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [QHeaderView](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qheaderview.htm) class also has two methods for saving and restoring it's state to and from a QByteArray: saveState()and restoreState()

A table view's headers are accessible via the horizontalHeader() and verticalHeader() methods.

Answer (score 0):

saveGeometry returns a QByteArray value, you need to store it somewhere.

Example:

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event){
    QSettings settings;

    settings.setValue("geometry", saveGeometry());
}
```

For reading the geometry call the restoreGeometry function:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):QMainWindow(parent) {
    [...]

    QSettings settings;

    restoreGeometry(settings.value("geometry").toByteArray());

    [...]
}
```

To learn more about window geometry please read [the documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/geometry.html)

Comment: I knew that already. I'm looking for a way to restore the layout of a QTableView, not only the window geometry.

Answer (score 0):

See the Qt documentation on [Restoring a Window's Geometry](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/geometry.html#restoring-a-window-s-geometry).

Comment: This doesn't store the geometry of the children of the window. (Not all of them should be stored though…)